# How can I solve the equation...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

$$\log\left(\frac{\pi_i}{1-\pi_i}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^K x_{ik}\beta_k\qquad i=1,2,\dots,N$$

How can I make the equation above the one below by taking "$e$" to both sides.

> Note that after taking $e$ to both sides of Eq. 1,
>   $$\frac{\pi_i}{1-\pi_i}=e^{\sum_{k=0}^K x_{ik}\beta_k}.$$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $log x=^elog x$

Answer (score 3):

$$\log{\frac{\pi_i}{1-\pi_i}}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^Kx_{ik}\beta_k$$
, take the exponential of both sides, 
$$e^{\log{\frac{\pi_i}{1-\pi_i}}}=e^{\sum\limits_{k=0}^Kx_{ik}\beta_k}$$
, use the rule $e^{\log{x}}=x$, 
$$\frac{\pi_i}{1-\pi_i}=e^{\sum\limits_{k=0}^Kx_{ik}\beta_k}$$

Comment: Thank you for the help and appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

The answer comes from the equality $e^{\log A}=A$

Comment: Note to the OP : in the real numbers, this is true only if $A > 0$ .